# How to prevent websites header and footer in android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, wordpress

I have a website which is built using WordPress, now I want to make an android app which will use this website. I want the header/footer to be dynamic as follows:

```
User access     | header displayed?
app             | no
android browser | yes
```

Any idea or suggestions how to do it? Is there any WordPress, android or JavaScript plugin which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a User-Agent on your web view in your Android app and then check the User-Agent in your WordPress templates to decide what to show/hide.

For instance, include `sitename-native-app` in your User-Agent. This explains how to set your User-Agent in Android: [android user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586197/android-user-agent)

On the WordPress side, create a function to check the User Agent. Example:

```
function is_native_app() {
    return ( false !== strpos( strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ), 'sitename-native-app' ) );
}
```

Then, in your template where you include your header and footer, wrap with:

`if ( ! is_native_app() ) { ... }`

Comment: can I user media query?

Comment: you can, if you use media query, you will hide headers for mobile browsers, ios devices etc too

Comment: You wouldn't be changing a function for media queries, you should find the style.css file of your template, and add @media (max-width: 768px) { #header{display:none;}.. } and so on.

Comment: Media query will hide your header and footer on **mobile web**, too.