# How to construct a custom User Agent string for Webview app in android?

Tags: android, user-agent

I have Webview in my app.Recently i tried to login in gmail but got Error "Error 403:disallowed_useragent".

From Documentation I used

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 4 Build/KRT16H) AppleWebKit/537.36
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

But my app crash

```
    E/chromium: [ERROR:validation_errors.cc(76)] Invalid message: VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED (safe_browsing.mojom.SafeBrowsing.0 )
E/chromium: [ERROR:render_process_host_impl.cc(4990)] Terminating render process for bad Mojo message: Received bad user message: Validation failed for safe_browsing.mojom.SafeBrowsing.0  [VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED (safe_browsing.mojom.SafeBrowsing.0 )]
    [ERROR:bad_message.cc(27)] Terminating renderer for bad IPC message, reason 123
E/chromium: [ERROR:validation_errors.cc(76)] Invalid message: VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED (network.mojom.URLLoaderFactory.0 )
E/chromium: [ERROR:render_process_host_impl.cc(4990)] Terminating render process for bad Mojo message: Received bad user message: Validation failed for network.mojom.URLLoaderFactory.0  [VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED (network.mojom.URLLoaderFactory.0 )]
    [ERROR:bad_message.cc(27)] Terminating renderer for bad IPC message, reason 123
E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (14677) crash detected (code -1).
E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(90)] Render process (14677) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing application.
```

So I like to know How to construct a user agent string which i can use for every site.I will be more thank full if someone tells me the importance of user agent.

Answer (score 0):

See [android user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586197/android-user-agent). For old versions of Android (API < 30) use:

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("user-agent-string");
```

User-agent tells the site what browser has a user. Depending on this value the site can change a behaviour (can load different contents or JavaScript), also it is used in analytics.