# Set user-agent in WebView for Android, API 30

Tags: android, android-webview, user-agent

After reading [android user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586197/android-user-agent) I set in WebView:

```
webView.settings.apply {
    userAgentString = "some string"
    javaScriptEnabled = true
    javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    domStorageEnabled = true
}
```

And loaded the URL "https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/". In emulators of API 21 and 29 it worked right. But in API 30 it showed:

[image]

How to change user-agent in API 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/03/chrome-phasing-user-agent/, Chrome will replace `User-Agent` with a new API called `Client Hints`.

Comment: according to https://www.chromium.org/updates/ua-reduction/#applicable-platforms, there are no any plans to ship this on iOS or Android WebView.